# Finding cummulative sum of MAX values

Tags: max, powerbi, dax

I need to calculate the cumulative sum of Max value per period (or per category). See the embedded image.

So, first, I need to find max value for each category/month per year. Then I want to calculate the cumulative SUM of these max values. I tried it by setting up max measure (which works fine for the first step - finding max per category/month for a given year) but then I fail at finding a solution to finding cumulative SUM (finding the cumulative Max is easy, but it is not what I'm looking for).

**Table1**

```
Year  Month  MonthlyValue  MaxPerYear
2016  Jan    10            15
2016  Feb    15            15
2016  Mar    12            15
2017  Jan    22            22
2017  Feb    19            22
2017  Mar    12            22
2018  Jan     5            17
2018  Feb    16            17
2018  Mar    17            17
```

**Desired Output**

```
Year  CumSum
2016  15
2017  37
2018  54
```

Comment: Why 16 rather than 17 for year 2018?

Comment: My mistake. Should be 17 of course

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49150526/dax-average-issue/) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52617947/how-to-get-average-from-a-measure-in-power-bi-desktop/) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52557178/the-dax-code-calculating-the-sum-of-maximum-values-per-day/) as far as subtotaling, but also includes a cumulative component as well.

You can do this in two steps. First, calculate a table that gives the max for each year and then use a cumulative total pattern.

```
CumSum = 
VAR Summary =
    SUMMARIZE(
        ALLSELECTED(Table1),
        Table1[Year],
        "Max",
        MAX(Table1[MonthlyValue])
    )
RETURN
    SUMX(
        FILTER(
            Summary, 
            Table1[Year] <= MAX(Table1[Year])
        ),
        [Max]
    )
```

Here's the output:

[image: CumSum]

If you expand to the month level, then it looks like this:

[image: CumSum Monthly]

---

Note that if you only need the subtotal to work leaving each row as a max (15, 22, 17, **54**) rather than as a cumulative sum of maxes (15, 37, 54, **54**), then you can use a simpler approach:

```
MaxSum =
    SUMX(
        VALUES( Table1[Year] ),
        CALCULATE( MAX( Table1[MonthlyValue] ) )
    )
```

This calculates the max for each year separately and then adds them together.

---

External References:

- [Subtotals and Grand Totals That Add Up “Correctly”](https://powerpivotpro.com/2012/03/subtotals-and-grand-totals-that-add-up-correctly/)
- [Cumulative Total - DAX Patterns](https://www.daxpatterns.com/cumulative-total/)