# Power BI - DAX Measure to calculate churned and reactivated customers in the current period. Incorrect total

Tags: powerbi, dax, datediff, measure

Below is a simplified version of the data. Daily transaction list for customer ID

```
SalesData = 
DATATABLE (
    "Customer ID", INTEGER,
    "Date", DATETIME,
    "Amount", INTEGER,
    {
         { 101245, "2019/04/07", 500 },
         { 101245, "2018/08/05", 400 },
         { 100365, "2018/07/30", 900 },
         { 100365, "2018/02/22", 700 },
         { 104300, "2019/04/05", 300 },
         { 104300, "2019/04/03", 350 },
         { 104300, "2019/04/01", 310 },
         { 107804, "2018/11/08", 650 },
         { 107804, "2018/11/19", 640 },
         { 108040, "2019/01/02", 730 }
    }
)
```

Objective: Calculate Reactivated and churned customers during the **current period** which in the example below is **1-7th April 2019**.

Churned = Inactive for 90 days or more.

Reactivated = Inactive for 90 days or more prior to making the latest purchase.

In a matrix - as visualized below - the following measures work as expected for reactivated and churned **in the current period, 1st to 7th of April**.

```
    churnedInCurrentPeriod = 
    VAR dayspassed =
    DATEDIFF(
        MAX(SalesData[Date]),
        CALCULATE(
            MAX(SalesData[Date]),
            ALLEXCEPT(SalesData,SalesData[Date])),
            DAY)
    Return 
    IF(dayspassed >= 90 && dayspassed <= 97,1,0)
```

Please note that the "current period" in this case needs to be dynamic to the date, thats why the date slicer is there and I use an allexpect on the date column to make it work. In the if statement it's 90 + 7 days, should be dynamic this as well.

```
ReactivatedInCurrentPeriod = 
VAR differenceDays =
DATEDIFF(
    CALCULATE(
        MAX(SalesData[Date]),
        FILTER(SalesData,SalesData[Date] <> MAX(SalesData[Date])
        )
    ),
    MAX(SalesData[Date]),
    DAY
)
RETURN 
IF(AND(differenceDays >= 90,MAX(SalesData[Date]) >= DATE(2019,4,1)),1,0)
```

[image]

As the screenshot show the matrix works as expected. Not the totals. I've tried using calculate with distinctcount to count the customers accordingly without success. Currently I solve this in my real dataset by exporting the matrix and sum in excel(!).

Has to be a better way to make this work with DAX.

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need a `Dates` table with no relationship to your `SalesData` table to use as a slicer. The following works well enough for purposes here:

```
Dates = CALENDAR( DATE( 2018, 1, 1 ), DATE( 2019, 12, 31 ) )
```

When you use that as a slicer, you can read the max and min dates to get a dynamic period like this:

```
ChurnedInPeriod =
VAR MaxDate = MAX ( Dates[Date] )
VAR MinDate = MIN ( Dates[Date] )
VAR CustomerLastDate = CALCULATE ( MAX ( SalesData[Date] ), SalesData[Date] <= MaxDate )
VAR DaysPassed = MaxDate - CustomerLastDate
VAR PeriodLength = MaxDate - MinDate
RETURN
    IF ( DaysPassed >= 90 && DaysPassed <= 90 + PeriodLength, 1, 0 )
```

This doesn't solve the subtotal problem, but you can now write a new measure that uses the above that does:

```
ChurnedCount = SUMX ( VALUES ( SalesData[Customer ID] ), [ChurnedInPeriod] )
```

The approach for reactivated accounts should be similar.

The key here is that you need to evaluate `ChurnedInPeriod` for each customer separately and that's exactly what `ChurnedCount` does. For each individual customer, it evaluates `ChurnedInPeriod` for that one and then adds them all together. This `SUMX ( VALUES( ... ), ... )` pattern is common for subtotals that need to be rolled up from lower granularity calculations.

---

Here's [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52953022) that discusses `SUMX ( VALUES ( ... ), ... )` and include further links.

Comment: Neat solution! works very well.

SUMX (VALUES ... is a great suggestion for solving similar problems. I'll be utilizing that going forward.

Thank you