# Wrong matrix totals

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to calculate a new column based on the date but the matrix totals is giving a wrong sum. Can someone suggest me a solution to this?
The totals of the last column is wrongly shown as $23M.

Basically, if the day has passed I want the actuals, if not, the forecast in 'New Buget(Sales)'

`New Budget (Sales) = IF([HasDayPassed] = "Yes", [Sales (SHP)],[Sales (SHP)]+[Sales FC2])

`[image]

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55615736/power-bi-dax-measure-to-calculate-churned-and-reactivated-customers-in-the-cur/) has a pretty similar issue with totals and might help.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that the matrix is not getting any row context when calculating total, [HasDayPassed] in your case.

You need to modify your measure for New Budget (sales) to something like:

```
New Budget (Sales) = 
VAR actual = CALCULATE(SUM([Sales (SHP)]), FILTER(Yourtable, [HasDayPassed] = "Yes"))
VAR forecast = CALCULATE(SUM([Sales (SHP)]) + SUM([Sales FC2]), FILTER(Yourtable, [HasDayPassed] = "No"))


RETURN IF(ISBLANK(actual),0,actual) + IF(ISBLANK(forecast),0,forecast)
```

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi Pratik, Thanks for your help. I tried the measure that you gave but it is not giving me Forecast values. All forecast values are 0. Could you please help me understand what is wrong with HasDayPassed? I am having trouble understanding.

Comment: @Spartan567 For that, I will need a look at HasDayPassed filter. Also, is total for actuals correct now, if we ignore the zeros in forecast?